# Exactness of short sequences of chain complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, derived-functors, functors

Given projective resolutions $P' \to A'$, $P \to A$ and $P'' \to A''$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ and a functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is an abelian category, I came up to the following situation:
For each $n$, the short sequence
$$0 \to F(P'_{n}) \to F(P_{n}) \to F(P''_n) \to 0$$
is exact. From this point, can I assume that the short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$0 \to F(P') \to F(P) \to F(P'') \to 0$$
is exact?

Comment: You are correct because this is just the definition.

Comment: I am asking because I'm trying to prove that the derived functors $L_{*}F$ form a homological $\delta$-functor, and in [Weibel book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Homological-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521559871/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491178305&sr=8-1&keywords=an+introduction+to+homological+algebra+weibel) he first shows that for each $n$ the short sequence above is split exact, and I dont understand why he needs the splitting part for that conclusion

Comment: @Luiza Sorice What Weibel says is that a short exact sequence of projective complexes $0 \to P' \to P \to P'' \to 0$ induces a s.e.s. $0 \to F(P') \to F(P) \to F(P'') \to 0$ Note that $F$ is not left exact, and this is possible because additive functors preserve split s.e.s. Your s.e.s. splits because you deal with projective objects.

Comment: @Luiza Sorice ...that's what Weibel says there, but actually, the s.e.s. $0\to P' \to P\to P'' \to 0$ is built via the "horseshoe lemma", and it is split by the construction.

Comment: @Don Alejo Thanks, now I get why Weibel says so quickly that the sequence was split exact and why he uses additive functor property. Muchas gracias :)